# Create parameters from an array?

Tags: puppet, theforeman

I'm new to ruby and I'm writing a puppet module to be accessed via Foreman.

I writing it to be used by Foreman's Smart Class Parameter so it can be configured from the Foreman web console.

I was trying to see how I could create a parameter for 48 possible ports a device might have. Instead of manually entering the ports I was wondering if it is possible to do this dynamically.

For example instead of this:

```
class ciscobaseconfig (
  $interface_description_lan = 'A LAN interface'
) {
  interface {
   'FastEthernet 0/1':
      description => $interface_description_lan
  }
  interface {
   'FastEthernet 0/2':
      description => $interface_description_lan
  }
}
```

I want to do this:

```
class ciscobaseconfig (
  $interface_description_lan = 'A LAN interface',
) {
  interface {
    (0..48).each do |i|
    "FastEthernet 0/#{i}":
      description => $interface_description_lan
    end
  }
}
```

Following a commenter's suggestion I tried this, but it doesn't not work:

```
class ciscobaseconfig (
  $interface_description_lan = 'A LAN interface',
) {

  arrInterfaces = Array(1..48)

  arrInterfaces.each{
    interface {
      |intNum| puts "FastEthernet 0/#{intNum}":
        description => $interface_description_lan
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ==>> arr = Array(1 .. 10)  =then=> arr.each { |x| puts "wadupp#{x}" }

Comment: Isn't that the same thing I'm doing? What would a complete example of that look like?

Comment: Removed the [ruby] tag as it is more confusing than relevant for this question.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to ruby and puppet so wasn't sure if was a ruby question or more a puppet DSL question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to declare 48 resources, using titles based on the resource index, and all with the same parameter values.  This must be implemented in Puppet DSL, of course, and though that has some similarities to Ruby, it is not Ruby.  It appears that that has contributed some confusion.

It is useful for this purpose to install the [puppetlabs-stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) module, which provides a wide variety of useful extension functions.  The one that will help us out here is `range()`.  Given stdlib installed, something like this should do the trick:

```
class ciscobaseconfig (
    $interface_description_lan = 'A LAN interface',
  ) {

  each(range('1', '48')) |portnum| {
    interface { "FastEthernet 0/${portnum}":
      description => $interface_description_lan
    }
  }
}
```

That does assume you are using Puppet 4, or else Puppet 3 with the future parser.  It can be done with the standard Puppet 3 parser, too, but not as cleanly:

```
class ciscobaseconfig (
    $interface_description_lan = 'A LAN interface',
  ) {

  $portnums = split(inline_template("<%= (1..48).to_a.join(',') %>"), ',')
  $ifc_names = regsubst($portnums, '.*', 'FastEthernet 0/\0')

  interface { $ifc_names:
      description => $interface_description_lan
  }
}
```

Note in particular that when an array is given as a resource title, it means you are declaring one resource for each element of the array, all with identical parameters.

Comment: I have stdlib in my modules folder and I can see it in Foreman under Puppet Classes so I guess its installed? But when I update this module's init.pp file with your code and run import from Foreman it doesn't see it (says "No changes detected.."). And just to be clear if use the code in my first example in this module's init.pp Foreman will upload it without issues.

Comment: @red888, the code in your first example is malformed, so certainly that specific code does not have the result you describe.  Did the version you previously used perhaps declare resources for all 48 ports?  There indeed shouldn't be any changes if the state you assert now matches the current state.

Comment: Your right it was malformed! I'm sorry I just fixed it. The code in the first example now works (Foreman Imports it without issue).

Comment: It looks like Foreman does not yet support Puppet 4.  I have added an example that should work with Puppet 3.